# Is there any phone that doesn't have sms inbox content provider?

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider, inbox

Is there any phone that doesn't have typical sms content provider ("content://sms/inbox")?

Or there is any phone that has different fields scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are tablets that don't have telephony services so I guess it's possible that it doesn't work or just doesn't contain anything :-)

Comment: True, but is there any device that is capable of sending/receiving sms messages but doesn't have such provider?

Answer (score 1):

Android is open-source, so, technically, a company doing a custom ROM could desactivate this kind of functionnality, but I think that if the phone is able to send/receive SMS, the content provider will still be there.